# Let link deside what radio button is checked

Tags: html, radio-button, checked

I have 3 links on a page, when clicking on one of the links, the radio button on the other page needs to be checked.

Looks like this:

```
<a href="page.html?amount=1">Go 1</a>
<a href="page.html?amount=2">Go 2</a>
<a href="page.html?amount=3">Go 3</a>
```

I have some checkboxes on the page.html which needs to be checked.

```
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="2" />
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="3" />
```

When click on Go 2, checkbox 2 needs to be checked.
Anyone knows what js needs to be written?

Comment: parse querystring and get value for variable amount and based on that put a condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="1" /> 1 <br>
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="2" /> 2 <br>
<input type="radio" name="amount" value="3" /> 3 <br>


<script>
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split('=');
        if (decodeURIComponent(pair[0]) == variable) {
            return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        }
    }
    }


var am=getQueryVariable("amount");
var allElems = document.getElementsByName('amount');
for (i = 0; i < allElems.length; i++) {
    if (allElems[i].type == 'radio' && allElems[i].value ==am ) {
        allElems[i].checked = true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Reference: getQueryVariable() function is taken from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript). Credit goes to @ Dorian Gray

Comment: Thank you very much, 

// I did search allot but couldnt find any usefull code for this specific. I'm not a coder

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get the querystring using Javascript - plenty of information on how to do that, one example:
[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

You'll then need to write some Javascript to select the radio button - again, a simple search is your friend:
[javascript check radio buttons automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762762/javascript-check-radio-buttons-automatically)

Top tip: use the search engine :)